# Receiving Data using Firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve Childs from The Firebase Database using this code (which is declared in `viewdidload`)

```
let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("UsersInfo").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)
rootRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

     let hello = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
     let usernamerecieved = hello["Username"] as! String
     let Emailrecieved = hello["Email"] as! String
     let bloodtyperecieved = hello["BloodType"] as! String

     globalusername = usernamerecieved (EDITED)

})
```

and I've declared a global variable as such

```
var globalusername = "user"
```

Im trying to extract the `usernamerecieved` variable and casting it on a Global Variable. However when I print the global variable later on in the `viewdidLoad` I still get the initial value of the `globalusername` which is "user".

Comment: Post JSON structure of your database.And check if you are receiving the `usernamerecieved` from the database , try printing it. And did it work after editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code : `usernamerecieved = globalusername` what you are doing in this line is that you are setting the value of the usernamerecieved to the value of globalusername i.e. 'user' 
It should be `globalusername = usernamerecieved`.

Also sometimes it takes time to retrieve data from the server reasons could be numerous - slow network connection, heavy data retrieving such as images etc. but before it could be completed (Retrieving Action From The Server) it might be possible that line in which you are printing the `globalusername` gets called first , even before the completionBlock off the observeEventType is even completed (since its asynchronous , somewhat similar to  `dispatch_async`).To tackle that you should call the printing call for `globalusername` inside the completionBlock or observe any change in it's value by using `addObserver` to the `globalusername`,which will let you know whenever the value of `globalusername` is changed or updated so that you can act accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

observeEventType's block is asynchronous, it is possible that by the time you read the globalusername var, the block has not been completed yet.

Try printing globalusername inside the block and see the value